# Excel 2013 Remove Broken Data Model

Tags: vba, excel, pivot

I created an ultra-simple dashboard-type tool using pivot tables and charts - the idea being, "keep it simple and it won't break." However, when I saved and closed the workbook and tried to open it again and refresh the data, I get these errors [image: <code>We couldn't load the Data Model. This may be because the Data Model in this workbook is damaged.</code>][image: VBA Error]

Every time I try to do anything related to those pivots, that error message pops up. How can I fix or remove the data model in this workbook to make it usable again?